# Every regular polygon is circumscribed by a circle

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Every triangle is circumscribed by a circle.  Every square is circumscribed by a circle.  I am looking for a textbook in plane geometry that verifies that every regular polygon is circumscribed by a circle.

Comment: Do you really need a whole textbook for proving that? A regular polygon is fixed (as a set) by some rotation around its centre, hence it is for sure a cyclic polygon. Or, simply: there is a centre and such point has the same distance from every vertex, so...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: If one's definition of "regular polygon" is that it has congruent sides and congruent angles, then the very existence of its center needs to be proven. (That, I believe, is the crux of this question.)

Comment: @Blue: in such a case, it is enough to show that the perpendicular bisectors of the sides go through a common point, by SAS, SSA or whatever.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I didn't say the proof was *difficult*. :)  Nevertheless, I believe this is the argument OP wants to see.

Comment: @Blue  I know that the argument is not hard.  I just don't want to bother with it.  Do you know of a reputable geometry textbook?

Comment: @Adelyn: *"I don't want to bother"*? Then why are you here? To get others to find your answers for you, because just looking for one is too much of a bother for you -- not to mention if you had to actually think about the answer? Ouch. *"I don't care if it is true or not, I just want to know if an authority said so."* Your attitude hurts.

Comment: @Nominal Animal  Dude, I am asking for a reference to a theorem.  I know the argument for it is tedious.  I do not want to take the time to prove it myself when there are textbooks that already have a carefully written explanation for it.  I didn't think I would have to explain this to anybody using this website.  Maybe you shouldn't be on this website.

Comment: @Adelyn: Or, perhaps you are mistaken, and this website is not your library assistant? Would it surprise you if somebody told you this site is about asking and answering actual questions, *working out mathematics problems*, rather than just references to authorities?

Comment: Adelyn, it's not obvious because many textbooks define regular polygons as equilateral and circumscribed by a circle. Then you must state on a particular precise definition and ask how to infere from it until the circumscribition by a circle.

Comment: @igael  I have not seen a definition for "regular polygon" as you have described.  And I have looked in many geometry textbooks.  If that is what you have seen, this is the cite to mention it.

Comment: @Adelyn:[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#General_properties) or more explicit the french wiki translated, see after "Characterizations" [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Ffr.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPolygone_r%25C3%25A9gulier%23Caract.C3.A9risations&edit-text=c%27est+du+g%C3%A2chis.&act=url)

Comment: @igael  At the website to which you provided a link, regular polygons are "defined" to be equilateral and equiangular.  A theorem presented on this website asserts that this is "equivalent to" a polygon that is equilateral and circumscribed by a circle.

Comment: @user143462: yes, it's not clear. I see the same differences with the construction of $R$ or $C$ etc. It depends from the set of assertions being assigned to be axiomatic in different constructions of the theories.

Answer (score 0):

All triangles which made of intersections by bisectors of each angle on regular polygon are congruent with equality of one side and both angles. So, all bisectors intersect at one point. The perpendicular's lengths for each side from the point are equal. Therefore that point is circumcenter.